# Initializing ** arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Suppose we declare an array of pointers to chars i.e. `char *a[3];`
I know that char ** is a pointer to a pointer to a char, so it is legal to do something like: `char ** c = arr;`

We can also declare something like `char **b[3];`, but I am confused about what this represents. I thought it would be a pointer to the pointer which points to the first element in b, but that would be the same thing as above. How do I initialize values in the array b and what are those values?

Comment: `char ** c = arr;` is legal provided that `arr` is declared before that and its type is what can be assigned to `char**`. `char **b[3];` is an 3-element of array of pointers to pointers to `char`. How to initialize depends on what you want to do.

Comment: One way to look at it is that `a` and `c` can be used to represent 2D arrays, whereas `b` is 3D.

Comment: `char **b[3]` declares `b` as an array of 3 elements, each of type `char **`.  That is, `b` is an array of objects the same type as your `c`, so, for example, you could write `b[0] = c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b is an array of char** that could store 3 elements of type char**. You could initialize as follows:

```
char  **a1, **a2, **a3;
char **b[3] = {a1, a2, a3};
```

and when accessing b[0] it would give you a1, b[1] would give you a2 and b[2] would give a3.